# Receiving an error: variable i is already defined in method main

Tags: java

I am trying to write a program that:
 1) asks for user input to create an array of 10 elements
 2) checks to make sure the elements are distinct
 3) identifies the highest value among the elements.

I think Im close but I keep receiving this error message:

error: variable i is already defined in method main(String[])
            for (int i = 0; i < myList.length; i++) {

Here is my full code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class max101 {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    double[] myList = new double[10];
    double max = myList[0];

    java.util.Scanner input = new java.util.Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter " + myList.length + " distinct numbers: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < myList.length; i++)
        myList[i] = input.nextDouble ();

    for(int i = 0; i <myList.length; i++) {

        for(int j = i+1; j<myList.length; j++) {

           if(myList[i] == (myList[j])); {
                System.out.println("Numbers are not distinct. Please try again and enter 10 distinct numbers");
           }

            if(myList[i] != (myList[j])); {
               for (int i = 0; i < myList.length; i++) {
                  if (myList[i] > max) max = myList[i];
                     System.out.println("The maximum value is " + max);
                  }
               }        
            }
         }
      }
   }
```

Comment: What do you think the error message means?

Comment: I would gather that it means that I dont need to continuing defining int i within the for loops

Answer (score 0):

1. Try using different variable names in your loops
2. If you dont want to do the above dont reinitialize the variable with `int` just put `i = 0`

It might also be useful to look into how scope works.

Answer (score 0):

My suspicion is you’re not ending your blocks properly — a block meaning from `{` to `}`. When I have my IDE indent your code, it is:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < myList.length; i++)
        myList[i] = input.nextDouble();

    for (int i = 0; i < myList.length; i++) {

        for (int j = i + 1; j < myList.length; j++) {

            if (myList[i] == (myList[j]))
                ;
            {
                System.out.println("Numbers are not distinct. Please try again and enter 10 distinct numbers");
            }

            if (myList[i] != (myList[j]))
                ;
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < myList.length; i++) {
                    if (myList[i] > max)
                        max = myList[i];

                    System.out.println("The maximum value is " + max);

                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I think you see now that `i` is declared inside a for loop that already declares `i`. Also once you’ve detected a duplicate I think you should break out of the two loops rather than checking for more duplicates, and not find a max until the user has entered 10 new numbers.

One more tip, don’t put a semicolon after your `if (` … `)`, it breaks your logic.